# Derivation of "anus" from "annulus"?

Tags: etymology, latin

I have always thought the word *annulus* to be exceptionally awkward. I'd like to know the relation between *annulus* and *anus*.

Geometrically, an annulus is a disk with a hole in it. The anal muscle ("sphincter") has an annular shape.

I'm wondering how we got from *annulus* to *anus*.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You have the derivation slightly backwards.  The Latin *anus* meant *ring* and thus also the anatomical *anus*.

Meanwhile *anulus* was a Latin diminutive of *anus*, so a *small ring*

Answer (score 6):

Both *anus* and *annulus* comes from Latin, where *anus* meant "a ring," and *annulus* meant "a little ring." The Latin *annulus* is derived from the Latin word *anus*.

The origin of *anus* is 16th century, and  the origin of *annulus* is Middle English.

Comment: Can it be that one of our most fantasized- and obsessed-over orifices was not named until the 16th century? Just my quick reaction, but how can this make sense?

Comment: @Pete: Wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Changes_to_Old_English_vocabulary) lists the following obsolete English words for it: *earsgang*, *setl*, and *ūtgang*.

Comment: @Alex - Fascinating, thanks! We can see that *ūtgang* is something like *out-going;* and the Wikipedia article relates the *ears-* of *earsgang* to *arse.*

Answer (score 1):

[Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=anus) has it "from PIE base *ano- 'ring.'" Interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Annulus is also related to annual, or the yearly cycle. Related to Anno Domini - Year of Our Lord. The double 'n' seems to be correct historically although they have a common origin.

Not necessarily surprising that anus may not have been named until the 16th C. The hip bone ("innominate") is the "unnamed" bone. The pudendal nerve (the one that goes numb if you've been riding a bike for too long) means "that which is not to be discussed" and is also related to the slang "pud".

Comment: Roy Film: It seems entirely plausible that "annulus" and "annual" share a common root. But can you provide a citation confirming that?